# How to get SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT to work?

Tags: python, django, ssl

I'm trying to have a single endpoint on my site that is not HTTPS (for some other service that does not support it). 
I have tried adding this to my settings.py as per: https://github.com/argenisosorio/django_ssl_secure_redirect

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_REDIRECT_URLS = ['^']
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = ['the_endpoint']
```

But it still redirects to HTTPS. Site is hosted on Heroku. Any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if you got this working, but SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT needs to be a list of regex, something like ['^the_endpoint$'] or ['^the_endpoint.*'] should work? And you can remove the SECURE_REDIRECT_URLS variable.